# string handling

Tags: c#, compact-framework

```
string str = "abc";
str = str + '\t';
```

this should print "abc    ".
But is is not working in compact framework application. Any help??

Comment: this should contain "relevant information". But it is ambigous. Any error??

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by `is is not working`....

Comment: Please note that strings in .NET are immutable so I would suggest you assign it all right away instead of appending to a string variable. Read up on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Comment: @Golez: it doesnt give any error

Comment: @shiv: it print "abc" only without appending tab to it

Comment: @Anant, Are you sure. Print something after the tab as well so you'll know for sure. Also try double quotes around the "\t", that could be the other reason why

Comment: @shiv: tried already. but it didnt worked.

Comment: @Anant, then it's just possible that controls in the Compact Framework don't display tabs? I haven't used Compact Framework in many years.

Comment: @shiv: just chked the same, i think u r right :)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me the way I expect it to:

```
string str = "abc";
str = str + '\t' + 'd'; // Without the 'd', how would I even know there's a tab?
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Output:

```
abc     d
```

What exactly is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: the same is not working for device application. Actually i am trying to insert tab in two strings, and pass the same as item to listbox so that it will look like two columns

Answer (score 0):

its a string...it gets printed 
remove the second line if u have to print abc only i.e
string str = "abc";
and then send print command...it will work...to print in c#
to see more on how to print see
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/pritingincsharp11222005040630am/pritingincsharp.aspx

hope this helps

Comment: i want to insert tab between two strings

Answer (score 0):

so now ur making sense....its a lot easier if u simply press the tab button with string abc.i.e
string str = "abc   "; this will work perfectly and if u really want to do it in second line...try

str = "abc";
str = str + '   ' + 'd'; //here instead of using \t use the actual tab...u can copy paste it using notepad or microsoft word....it should work fine...

Comment: actually lisbox dont accept tab character. So your statement will work and when i ll pass that string as item to listbox tabs will be disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see what encoding you're using or what encoding is supported on the compact device framework you're using?  Perhaps \t is not supported in the same manner.

reference:

[Encoding and Localization in the .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k15k55d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)